# How to write remaining amount in python

Tags: python

I wrote a code like the following and I want to subtract the amount spent from the income and print the remaining amount on the screen, but I could not do it. How do I do it and where am I going wrong?

```
income = int(input('Enter your income: '))
expense = int(input('Type your expense: '))
if income >= expense:
     x = income-expense
     print(f'Your Remaining: {x}')
else:
     y = expense-income
     print(y)
x = income-expense
remainder = (int(x))
fruit = int(input("Amount to be paid for fruit: "))
vegetable = int(input(("Amount to be paid to vegetable: "))
result = fruit+vegetable
if x >= result:
print(f"You have received the products. Amount spent on fruit: {fruit}, amount spent on vegetables: {vegetable}")
else:
print(f"You don't have enough money. Amount spent on fruit: {fruit}, amount spent on vegetables: {vegetable}")
money = remainder-result
print(f"Remaining money {money}")
```

Comment: This is not a [mre]. We can't see the definitions for `money`, `expenditure`, or `result`. Also, if your remainder is a string (since you did `remainder = (str(x))`), then there's no way you can subtract something from it, since you can only subtract from numbers. The code you posted is in no way runnable. Your `if` statement's indentation is also not correct; your `else` statements and their contents are not properly indented. Since indentation is critical in Python, you need to fix it.

Comment: Not to mention a floating `else`.

Comment: My bad, there is the definition for `money`, but the second `if` statement's indentation is still off. And we can't see the definition for `expenditure`. Also if `if income >= expense` returns `False`, then the line `remainder = (str(x))` will throw an exception because `x` was never defined. Unless it's defined elsewhere in your code. But either way this is still not quite a [mre].

Comment: thank you, I solved the problem, I took the "remainder" expression as "str" expression, the problem was caused by this. When I fixed it to "int" the problem disappeared.

Comment: At the same time, I tried to operate without assigning the "x" variable, when I assign the x method, the problem is solved. I add updates

Answer (score 0):

Let's dive into your code, bro

```
income = int(input('Enter your income: '))
expense = int(input('Type your expense: '))
if income >= expense:
     # it should be expense(as expenditure is not defined)
     # x = income - expense
     x = income-expenditure
     print(f'Your Remaining: {x}')
else:
     y = expense-income
     print(y)
# if you convert a number into string, then you can't apply arithmetic operations on it.
# if your income is smaller than expense, then x will never be defined, so it will give error in that case too
remainder = (str(x))
fruit = int(input("Amount to be paid for fruit: "))
vegetable = int(input(("Amount to be paid to vegetable: ")))
result = fruit+vegetable
if x >= result:
print(f"You have received the products. Amount spent on fruit: {fruit}, amount spent on vegetables: {vegetable}")
else:
print(f"You don't have enough money. Amount spent on fruit: {fruit}, amount spent on vegetables: {vegetable}")
money = remainder-result
print(f"Remaining money {money}")
```

Try this code:

```
income = int(input('Enter your income: '))
expense = int(input('Type your expense: '))
remainder = income - expense
if remainder >= 0:
     print(f'Your Remaining: {remainder}')
else:
     print('Reduce your expenses dude !!')

fruit = int(input("Amount to be paid for fruit: "))
vegetable = int(input(("Amount to be paid to vegetable: ")))
result = fruit+vegetable
if remainder >= result:
print(f"You have received the products. Amount spent on fruit: {fruit}, amount spent on vegetables: {vegetable}")
else:
print(f"You don't have enough money. Amount spent on fruit: {fruit}, amount spent on vegetables: {vegetable}")
money = remainder-result
print(f"Remaining money {money}")
```

Happy Coding to you bro !!